# Javascript Skips Intervals in For Loop

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop in JavaScript that is skipping intervals regularly and I can't determine why.

```
console.log(parseInt($('input.num-to-add').val()));
numToAdd = parseInt($('input.num-to-add').val());
console.log(numToAdd);
for(i=0;i<numToAdd;i++){
    console.log('Running loop for ' + i + '...');
    // the following code won't mean much
    // but it was noted that the full code should be present
    table.find('tbody').prepend(data.html);
    var row = table.find('tbody #add-location-row').first();
    rowInit(row);
}
```

As you can see, I'm, `console.log`ing at just about every step and I just can't identify the issue. The issue itself is pretty well illustrated in the console output. For example, if `input.num-to-add` has a value of `8`, here's what I see in the console:

```
8
8
Running loop for 0...
Running loop for 6...
Running loop for 7...
```

I really can't see what the issue would be here. This seems to me to be incredibly simple and basic code but it's breaking in some way I simply can't determine.

Comment: Its a plain old closure issue. Use `for(let i=0;i<numToAdd;i++){`

Comment: What @RajaprabhuAravindasamy said is correct, I'd also note that in general it's better to save out your data first so you only perform the query once for however my times you need the data set, in other words, set `numToAdd`, and then after you can log it, `console.log(numToAdd)`. In this case not a big deal but I've seen people repeatedly query the same data over and over and it makes me very sad.

Comment: Turk: I'm... pretty sure that's what I did? I `console.log`ed both the value from the input AND the saved variable just to check where on earth this issue could be coming from. And Raj, that fixed it, thank you! I'll be honest, I'm not 100% up on JavaScript, could you explain how that solved things? If you post it as an answer I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: I don't see how anybody can have any confidence that they know what the problem is. Clearly if `...` were no code at all the code as posted would work.

Comment: Pointy, I've added the full code. I still don't see how any of that would affect the for loop.

Comment: What does `rowInit90` do? The variable `i` in the code you posted is a **global** variable .

Comment: @PeregrineStudios, look at the difference between this

`console.log(parseInt($('input.num-to-add').val()));`
`numToAdd = parseInt($('input.num-to-add').val());`

and this

`numToAdd = parseInt($('input.num-to-add').val());`
`console.log(numToAdd);`

PS no amount of formatting allows newlines in comments apparently, hopefully that's still readable

Comment: The problem: You don't declare the variable `i`, so it is global, and you use it in another funtion where it get the wrong value in your loop.

Comment: It finds `select` elements in the row and runs `select2()` on them, and finds `input.datepicker` elements in the row and runs `datepicker()` on them. Basically, just initializes some plugin elements.

Comment: Turk: I think you're missing, I do BOTH of those things: `console.log(parseInt($('input.num-to-add').val()));` - `numToAdd = parseInt($('input.num-to-add').val());` - `console.log(numToAdd);`. I did them both in the process of debugging, to check if there was somehow a disparity between the variable value and 'queried' value. -- And thank you some and Pointy, I fully understand what the problem was now!

Comment: @PeregrineStudios look just declare your local variables with `var` or `let`.

Comment: I bet you use `i` without declaration in `rowInit` or one of the function it calls.

Comment: @PeregrineStudios, yea but that data doesn't just change over run time. Once you've saved the data, you have it. Additional queries are just additional queries that are wasting cycles on data you already have. If the data in that variable was changing then that'd be one thing, but `i` not iterating is your issue; therefore the problem isn't with your data set, no need to do multiple queries for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As many others already pointed out in the comments section, that most certainly happens because you use a *global* variable named `i` as a loop variable. If you use the same global variable `i` in `rowInit`, that will interfere with this loop. Solution is simple, always use correctly scoped variables:

```
for(var i=0;i<numToAdd;i++){
    console.log('Running loop for ' + i + '...');
    // the following code won't mean much
    // but it was noted that the full code should be present
    table.find('tbody').prepend(data.html);
    var row = table.find('tbody #add-location-row').first();
    rowInit(row);
}
```

Or even better:

```
for(let i=0;i<numToAdd;i++){
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this answer was arrived at by others in the comments as well, however this was the first actual posted answer. Full credit to all who noted the issue!